# Integral operator with Bessel kernel

Tags: operator-theory, special-functions

For $x,y\ge 0$, let
$$
k(x,y)= \frac {J_1(2\sqrt{xy})}{\sqrt{xy}},
$$
where $J_1$ is the the Bessel function of the first kind
$$
J_{1}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k} \frac{\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2 k+1}}{k !(k+1) !}.
$$
Does this kernel give a bounded linear operator on $L^2(0,+\infty)$:
$$
 Af(x) =\int_{0}^\infty k(x,y) f(y) dy.
$$
Note that the kernel $k(x,y)$ is not square-integrable since
$$
\int_0^\infty \left( \frac {J_1(2\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2 dx= 1.
$$

Cross post [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3725239/integral-operator-with-bessel-kernel)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. A sufficient conditions for the boundedness of an integral operator in $L^2(0,\infty)$ of the form
$$Tf(x)=\int_0^\infty K(xy)f(y)\, dy$$ is
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{|K(x)|}{\sqrt x}\, dx =C <\infty.$$ If $K$ is positive the above condition is also necessary and $C$ yields the norm. In our situation $K(x)=\frac{J_1(2 \sqrt x)}{\sqrt x}$ and
$$C=\int_0^\infty \frac{|J_1(2\sqrt x)|}{x}<\infty $$ since $J_1(x) \approx x, x \to 0$ and $|J_1(x)| \le \frac {C}{\sqrt x}, x \to \infty$.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much. Do you by any chance know standard/textbook reference for this sufficient condition? Is there a special name for operators with the kernels K(x,y)=K(xy)?

Comment: It is easier if I explain how to do: write $$Tf(x)=\int_0^\infty K(z) \frac{f(z/x)}{x} dz$$ and use Minkowski for integrals that is $$\|Tf\|_2 \le \int_0^\infty |K(z) \|f(z/x)1/x\|_2\, dz$$ (the last $L^2$-norm is with respect to $x$). After changing variable in the $x$-integral you get the formula above. Another way is go to the line writing $x=e^t, y=e^s$ and, after some manipulation one sees that the above formula is equivalent to Young estimate for convolutions with a L^1 function.